# What would be the best way to copy folders to a folder with a sub folder and zip them up using gulpjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, npm, gulp

Currently I've got:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('copyFolderOne', function () {
  return gulp.src('folderOne/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('copyFolderTwo', function () {
  return gulp.src('folderTwo/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/sub_folder/'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('default', ['copyFolderOne', 'copyFolderTwo'], function () {
  return gulp.src('dist/**')
    .pipe($.zip('my_zip.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe($.size());
});
```

to copy two folders to a folder with sub a folder and zip them up using gulp.

This works. But I have to create two extra tasks and I'm not sure if I take advantages of streams. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the stream and rename the file after the copy task

references:
[merge-stream](https://github.com/grncdr/merge-stream)
[gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename)